# How to get full HTML code onClick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml, outerhtml

I have the below HTML code

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

When I click on the link, I want my string to contains the full HTML code below

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

I tried using this method, but I only manage to get the text "Google", can't get the anchor code.

```
$('#frame').contents().find('body').on("click", "a",  function () {
    var string = $(this).html();
    alert(string);
});
```

String alert only `Google` when I need `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`this.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML), or wrap the element in a container, and use `.html()` on that container.

```
$('#frame').contents().find('body').on("click", "a",  function () {
    var string = this.outerHTML;
    alert(string);
});
```

I prefer `outerHTML`, but Firefox has only recently added support for it. So, to account for these browsers, the second method might be preferred.

Comment: If you need a cross-browser way of getting `outerHTML`, you can use this plugin: http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/

Comment: the second way can be used somewhat like this: `$(this).clone().wrap('<span/>').parent().html()`

Comment: Thank you Rob! That solves it. I didnt know there's something like outerHTML.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. :)